# Approximate probabilities of passing a NIST statistical test

Tags: reference-request, random-number-generator

I am working with random number generation and testing, so I'm using NIST statistical tests to examine my random numbers. Now I want to compare my solution with other RNGs, but i can't find any probabilities of passing a NIST statistical test for them. So does anyone have that info? Info about both PRNGs and TRNGs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [TestU01](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html). It's another testing suite that has NIST built in. It also has implementations of most of the well-known RNGs, so you can compare. The documentation may have some results listed in it.